# Add an item to my own Amazon cart through the API

Tags: amazon-web-services

I would like to add an item to my own Amazon cart through the API.

Simplified use case: I have a specific product ID in mind. When I'm running low on that product, I press a button in an iPad app and it will make an authenticated callout to Amazon to add this item to my cart.

I've looked at the Product Advertising API, mainly the Add to Cart Form and CartAdd operation, but it doesn't look like that's what I want - me adding an item to my own cart.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/AddToCartForm.html

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/CartAdd.html

Is there even a way to do this?

Comment: Those links seeem to provide what you're looking for. Have you tried anything?
You should ask for help with your existing code...